# Unable to opening or perviewing office documents in browser in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps

Recently we migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. We have separately configured office web app. We get error

e.g while opening or previewing word document (Sorry there was a problem and we can't open this document. If this happens again, try opening the document in Microsoft Word.).

We tried multiple solutions found by searching in google but still error persist. In uls log we get error like

> (Application error when access /_vti_bin/wopi.ashx, Error=Method not
>   found: 'System.String
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtilityInternal.GetSharingUrl(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb,
>   System.Guid, Int32)'.
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Wopi.RunCheckFile(HttpContext
>   context, CommonRequestData requestData, CommonResponseData
>   responseData)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Wopi.ProcessRequestCore(HttpContext
>   context, CommonRequestData requestData, CommonResponseData
>   responseData)
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Wopi.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously))

We stuck at this point. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of office are you running, 2010 or 2013 ? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: If you disassembly the Microsoft.SharePoint dll you will indeed see that there is no such function (at least not with that parameter set). I'm guessing something was not upgraded correctly.

Comment: 2013 64 bit. After this we did 2 experiments        1) took backup of same SP 2013 web application and restored it in new SP 2013 web application then bound same office web apps with that and it works 2) We created new SP 2013 fresh web application in same server and bound same office web apps and that one also works. That might be correct that something was not upgraded correctly but how do we know this? Any suggestion?

Comment: On what OWA updates version you are?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanTahir We finally changed out SharePoint server and all work now.